# event machine gem bundle install is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following a tutorial and had to do a bundle install following the forking & cloning of a repository. Subsequently we are instructed to run bundle install. However, it is not working and I am getting the following error message:

```
make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
compiling cmain.cpp
In file included from cmain.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int,
 const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: 'fstati64' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0
.0/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmach
ine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm rather stuck on what to do at this point. I am on a Windows machine, any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by installing the latest version of the Eventmachine gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/eventmachine

And then subsequently instaling the latest version of the SQLite gem:
http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby

You might be prompted to update your Gemlockfile make sure to do that then everything else should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` Or `sudo gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` and then retry `bundle install`.

Some gem needs sudo privileges to install.

For windows `gem install eventmachine --pre`. Its a known issue for window with ruby 1.9. `https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/319`

Comment: I did gem install eventmachine --pre and it installed a version succesfully but failed to make it, I then changed the gemfile lock to eventmachine (1.0.0.beta.2) and was able to bundle install that way. I'll come back and update if I ran into any problems with this fix.